# Http Redirection for certain requests

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, http-redirect

I am helping someone set up an old ASP site. We won't go into how bad the site is organized but it is what it is. What the owner needs is if a user requests the url with no page it needs to redirect to another folder location.

thesiteurl.com would need to redirect to thesiteurl.com/folder1

but 
thesiteurl.com/information.asp?SID=1233 would need to launch the page in the site root.

Any ideas how that can be accomplished?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information I will just you the simplest answer. You could just do a redirect on thesiteurl.com/index.asp to /folder1.

Place this in index.asp...

```
<% response.redirect("/folder1") %>
```